# Creating custom page for checkout page does not work

Tags: learnpress

I am trying to add a content before checkout form in LearnPress so I created a custom checkout page inside child theme using the following code:

```
function custom_content_before_checkout() {
    // Check if the current page has a post ID of 1463
    if (is_page(1463)) {
        echo '<div class="custom-content">';
        echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Data 3</td><td>Data 4</td></tr>';
        echo '</table>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
add_action('learn_press_checkout_before_checkout_form', 'custom_content_before_checkout');
```

No content showed on the front-page.

I created the above-listed function code and I want to know what's wrong with the code

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems perfect however ensure that the page ID you are checking with is_page(1463) is correct. Verify that the LearnPress checkout page indeed has an ID of 1463. If it's a different ID, you should use the correct ID.

Comment: I was able to filter the “Buy Now” button text to say “Learn More” with url link to page ID 1463. While it redirects to the desired page, my custom content does not appear only the checkout form. Hiding the checkout Div does not work either

Answer (score 0):

The original code I had though was good but did not work for what I was trying to do and it took me a day to figure out that it's just more simple than I thought.

Here is how I solved the problem:

1. I filtered the Buy Now inside the course to say "Learn More"
2. In my child theme, I created this folder structure learnpress/checkout and I copied all the checkout files into the subfolder but only form.php actually works.
3. I echoed dummy texts just before the checkout form tag in the form.php and the text showed on frontend.

The only problem I wish I could solve is to add the content via the editor but I am okay adding and styling the content inside the child theme code